# How to iterate through the children of a Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the current structure in my component:

```
<data-table>
    <template slot="column" field="a"></template>
    <template slot="column" field="b"></template>
    <template slot="column" field="c"></template>
</data-table>
```

How do I iterate through these "columns" when rendering my `data-table`?

Edit: turns out adding refs to my columns didn't work, since according to the docs the refs are only stored in their variable when the components are actually rendered. Instead, I used the `$slots` variable to iterate over the columns on the `mounted` method, like this:

```
mounted: function() {
    this.$slots.column.forEach(
        //my code...
    );
}
```

Comment: You could assign a `ref` to each of them https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements (possibly not the best solution, but the first that came to mind), ie `<template slot="column" field="a" ref="col_1"></template>`

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned, `$ref` is the best approach to doing what you want. *Use `ref` carefully. It can get heavy on the user's machine.*

`// template`

```
<data-table>
    <template slot="column" field="a" ref="columns"></template>
    <template slot="column" field="b" ref="columns"></template>
    <template slot="column" field="c" ref="columns"></template>
</data-table>
```

`// script`

```
{
  ...
  mounted() {
    this.$refs.columns.forEach(col => {
      // Do something with `col`
      console.log(col)
    })
  }
}
```

Basically, if you have more than 1 `ref` with an identical name (like `'columns'`), that reference will be converted to a `VueComponent[]` (i.e. an array of vue components).

Comment: I had no idea refs handled multiple elements that smoothly. Sweet!

Comment: `this.$refs.columns` is `undefined` when I try to check the length of the array

Answer (score 0):

When you create slots, you can set dynamic names. Sample component:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td v-for="(slot,ind) in loopdata">
     <slot :name="'col'+ind" :data="slot"></slot>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

then use slots:

```
<data-table>
    <template slot="col1" slot-scope="{data}"></template>
    <template slot="col2" slot-scope="{data}></template>
    <template slot="col3" slot-scope="{data}></template>
</data-table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried a v-for iteration when rendering your `data-table`?, and create the columns based on a data property?

Such as:

`<template v-for="(col,index) in columns" slot="col.column" field="col.a"></template>`